# Xubuntu 14.04 - Confirmation dialog box doesn't appear after hitting shift + del shortcut

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, 14.04, xfce, delete

When I try to permanently delete a file or folder from desktop on Xubuntu 14.04 (using shift + del shortcut) no confirmation dialog box appears before they're excluded from computer.
It seems to be a xfdesktop issue, since this problem doesn't occur on nautilus or thunar.

Comment: I have the same issue. Restarting thunar and/or xfdesktop has no effect on it. A bug was raised in Xfce's bugzilla but there has been no action on it (except for my +1): [https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10857](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10857)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a bug that's been fixed upstream but not in Xubuntu yet. I think the best thing to do right now if you're having this issue is go to the Launchpad bug report and let them know the bug is affecting you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfdesktop4/+bug/1315716

That should bring more attention to the bug which should hopefully help it get fixed sooner.